# when i am trying to install npm install gulp -D in cmd prompt there many errors displaying

Tags: laravel

- node verison:v12.4.0
- npm verison:6.13.4
- laravel:5.8

> Build failed with error code: 1
>
> npm WARN The package popper.js is included as both a dev and production depende
>   cy.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fs
>   vents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents
>   1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
>   )
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional lo
>   ging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\CLOUD TIMON\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-31T05
>   00_45_654Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

first try to clean npm cache with :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then delete `node_modules` folder completely, then again run `npm install`.
that should solve the problem.

Comment: there is two node_modules floders , one is in my project directory and other one is in node.js where i delete this folders

Comment: when i run npm cache clean --force cmd it shows npm warns using --force i sure hope what your doing

Comment: @VYSHNAVIMADDALA do not be afraid of warnings what do you mean 2 node_modules folder ? absolutely when someone refers to your node_modules folder they mean in your project's folder.delete it and run above ! it does nothing but reinstalling every thing.

Comment: remember , warns are not always bad things, it depend on what they are saying, by force you do mean to clear cache , you do not want your program to depend on cache to work correctly ! cache is cache :) , (big sentence), working code is something else .